# Spring Boot and ObjectMapper configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 1.2.2 to create an Spring MVC application. I am also using Spring HATEOAS.

The issue I am having is that my configured ObjectMapper is used properly when my controller methods return a `List<>`, but a different ObjectMapper is being used when I return my `Resource` classes (e.g. `MyClass extends ResourceSupport`)

It's a more than a little frustrating to try to [configure Jackson's ObjectMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper). I have followed the documentation and added my own `ObjectMapper` `@Bean` to a `@Configuration` class and annotated it with `@Primary`, and that one is being used when serializing `List<>`.

Setting a breakpoint in the ObjectMapper constructor breakpoint reveals that the constructor is called about 20 times. I made a poor summary of each scenario:

1. My configuration class (`@Bean` annotated with `@Primary`)
2. halObjectMapper
3. WebMvcConfigurationSupport->requestMappingHandlerAdapter()->AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter->Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
4. configureMessageConverters()->Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
5. potentiallyRegisterModule()->Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
6. WebMvcConfigurationSupport->addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolver()->AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter->Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
7. 2 times: WebMvcConfigurationSupport->addDefaultHttpMessageConverters()->AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter->Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
8. 12 times: EndpointMBeanExporter (Spring Boot Actuator)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend either using `application.properties` to configure Jackson or, if you need more control, declaring your own `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean. In either case, you end up with a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean in the application context that can then be used by other components to create `ObjectMapper`s with your desired configuration or to apply that configuration to any existing `ObjectMapper`s.

Edit: there's [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2393) open to improve Actuator's `ObjectMapper` usage.

Comment: I will have to revisit the "more control" approach, because when I tried switching to that neither my resources nor lists of resources would serialize correctly. What I have found is that the halObjectMapper is what is serializing the standalone resources. I used @Qualifier to get a reference to it and ran it through my Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder, and that has solved my problem... for now.

Comment: Spring Boot should configure the HAL ObjectMapper for you using the builder: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/hateoas/HypermediaAutoConfiguration.java#L128. If that's not happening then you may have found a bug

Comment: I'll confirm and see if I can dig into why it might be happening. Thanks!

Comment: Turned on debug, turns out: "Ancestor 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration$HypermediaConfiguration' did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)". This is apparently because LinkDiscoverers is being created here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/config/HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java#L134

Comment: Sounds like you've used `@EnableHypermedia` in your app. As [described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-hateoas) that disables auto-configuration of Spring HATEOAS including the configuration of its ObjectMapper

Comment: Ah. I hadn't seen that in the documentation. Is that behavior that was added in Spring Boot 1.2 or has it been around for a while?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Jackson using spring boot `application.properties`.

See class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties`
or using Spring Tool Suite, simply edit your `application.properties`,
start typing `spring.jackson.` then hit `Ctrl-Space` to see the available properties.